# if variable exists in col 1 of a file, set a separate variable equal to the corresponding value in col 2

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I'm writing a script to run a grep for an input, create a file list and grep that file list in a separate directory and print the results.

```
echo "enter term"
read term
grep -rc "$term" /prod/directory1 | grep -v ":0" | sed -s 's%:[0-9]*%%' > file_list.txt
grep -rl --file=file_list.txt /tmp/directory2 > results.txt
```

but i would like to add an if statement that will identify if the $term is equal to a value in the first column of another file, and then set a new variable to the corresponding value in column 2 of that file.

```
echo "enter term"
read term

for i in products.txt; do
    if [[ $term = $i ]]; then
        var2 = $2
        echo "product code set to: "$var2
    else
        var2 = 0
        echo "product code set to 0."
    fi
done    

grep -rc "$term" /prod/directory1 | grep -v ":0" | sed -s 's%:[0-9]*%%' > file_list.txt
    if [[ ! $var2 = 0 ]] ; then
        grep -rc "var2" /prod/directory1 | grep -v ":0" | sed -s 's%:[0-9]*%%' >> file_list.txt
sed -s 's%.properties%%' file_list.txt | sort -u > file_list.txt
grep -rl --file=file_list.txt /tmp/directory2 > results.txt
```

the new grep will return results with .properties at the end, so I remove them and also any duplicate files from the list. Below is a sample for products.txt

```
Product_1    productCode_1
Product_2    productCode_2
Product_3    productCode_3
```

I would like the script to identify whether $term is in column one of that file, and then set $var2 equal to the corresponding productCode in column two. I believe once that variable is set everything else will work out nicely but right now it fails at:

```
for i in products.txt; do
    if [[$term = $i ]]; then
        var2 = $2
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance, I'm relatively new to bash scripting so I apologize in advance for my ineptitude.

Comment: i edited it to include the space, however this hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var2=$(awk -v term="Product_2" '$1==term{print $2}' products.txt)
```

Change Product_2 to read from another variable, if required.

Comment: @anishane I tried this: `for i in products.txt; do if [[ $term = $i ]] ; then set var2 = $(awk -v term="$term" '$1==term{print $2}' products.txt); echo "var2 is set to "$var2; fi done` but the echo doesn't return a value.

Comment: issue resolved.. i had a space between the var, =, and $(function).. This works nicely, thank you for your help @anishane